# Retrieve 2D co-ordinate from a 3D point on a 3D plane

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry, 2d, plane

I have a point a point (x, y, z) that is on a plane defined by ax+by+cz+d=0.  I'm trying to figure out what the (x', y') relative to the plane, where it has a starting point of (x0, y0, z0) and the x'-axis is defined by (1,0) and the y'-axis is defined by (0,1).

My major goal is to have the mouse click on a surface, and know the 2D co-ordinates on a particular surface.  I've managed to intersect the ray onto a plane quite trivially.

As a side-note, I'm using DirectX 9 - my familiarity with matrix/vector math is limited by the APIs provided to me through the D3DX libraries.

One thought I had was to use the angle of between one of the axis vectors and find the distance from origin, and figure out the x/y using simple trig.  But I'm not sure if that's really an ideal solution or not - or if it can actually solve the issue at hand.

Comment: The definition of the axes is unclear, since you use 2d coordinates for these. You have to somehow relate these axes to your 3d environment, or specify that you don't care about the orientation of these axes relative to its surroundings.

Comment: @MvG I think the context of my goal clarifies what I'm trying to achieve and what relevance my axes have.

Comment: If it were clear to me, I wouldn't have asked… And since your comment didn't clarify either, I fear I cannot help with this.

Comment: @MvG Sorry, I figured you might've missed it. Imagine a 2D image on a 3D plane.  When I click on a pixel on the screen, I'd like to know the x,y co-ordinates of that 2D image.  I have the 3D co-ordinate on the plane (I've already projected the ray out and made the intersection on the plane) - I'm trying to get the 2D co-ordinate of the image from the 3D plane I've done intersection with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a 2D image on that plane, you apparently want to match its coordinate system. To do so, determine the unit vectors of the picture. That is, take the 3d coordinates *B* for the picture position (x,0) for any x>0, and subtract from that the 3d coordinates *A* for the origin (0,0) of the picture. The resulting vector *B − A* will describe the positive *x* direction of your image. Do the same for the *y* direction. Then normalize both these vectors. This means dividing them by their length, sqrt(x²+y²+z²), but D3Dx has a function [`D3DXVec3Normalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this. Let's call the resulting 3d vectors *X* and *Y*. To compute the *x* and *y* coordinate of any 3D point *p*, simply subtract the origin *A* from *p*, i.e. compute the vector *p − A*. Then compute the dot product between the result and the unit vectors *X* and *Y*. This will give you two numbers: the desired coordinates. This is because the dot product can be used to compute an orthogonal projection.

Translating this into [D3Dx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172965%28VS.85%29.aspx), it should look somewhat like the following. As I have never used it, this might have mistakes.

```c
D3DXVECTOR3 *p;                  // input point
D3DXVECTOR3 a, b, c, ab, ac, ap; // helper vectors
FLOAT x, y;                      // output coordinates
imagePosTo3D(&a, 0, 0);          // a = origin of image
imagePosTo3D(&b, 1, 0);          // b = anywhere on positive x axis, perhaps a corner
imagePosTo3D(&c, 0, 1);          // c = anywhere on positive y axis, perhaps a corner
D3DXVec3Subtract(&ab, &b, &a);   // ab = b - a
D3DXVec3Subtract(&ac, &c, &a);   // ac = c - a
D3DXVec3Normalize(&ab, &ab);     // ab = ab / |ab|
D3DXVec3Normalize(&ac, &ac);     // ac = ac / |ac|
// the above has to be done once for the image, the code below for every p
D3DXVec3Subtract(&ap, p, &a);    // ap = p - a
x = D3DXVec3Dot(&ab, &ap);       // x = ab∙ap
y = D3DXVec3Dot(&ac, &ap);       // y = ac∙ap
```

Comment: As I mentioned, my math skills aren't quite what you're expecting...  Would you be able to provide more specifics/examples or something?