# creating end-caps for sliced mesh

Tags: c#, 3d, mesh

I'm working on a clipping algorithm with a mesh with and a given plane, it already slices the mesh, but I need to cover the holes with one or more 2d polygons, I already have all the 3d points that represent the polygons , so the next step would be to generate the triangles representing the polygons, I already found an algorithm to triangulate a 2d polygon, but I'm having troubles understanding : "**How to transform 3d points to 2d with a given plane**"

I found this link : [Retrieve 2D co-ordinate from a 3D point on a 3D plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699259/retrieve-2d-co-ordinate-from-a-3d-point-on-a-3d-plane)

but Im not sure what does **imagePosTo3D** do.

any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well it seems that I found the answer in here :

http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/16529/86429.aspx

```
Vector3 up = Vector3.Normalize(plane.N);
Vector3 right = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(up, Math.Abs(plane.N.X) > Math.Abs(plane.N.Z) ? Vector3.UnitZ : Vector3.UnitX));
Vector3 backward = Vector3.Cross(right, up);

Matrix4 transformMatrix = new Matrix4(right.X, up.X, backward.X, 0, right.Y, up.Y, backward.Y, 0, right.Z, up.Z, backward.Z,0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

and then multiply the transformMatrix by each 3d point and use the x and z coordinates